# Unable to autoload constant controller (in production). No error in development

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services

File name -

`app/controllers/invoice/inventory/department/pharmacy_invoices_controller.rb`

File content -

```
class Invoice::Inventory::Department::PharmacyInvoicesController < ApplicationController
...
end
```

I get no error in development but in production I get this error -

```
F, [2016-04-25T13:08:00.754597 #13500] FATAL -- :
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Invoice::Inventory::Department::PharmacyInvoicesController, expected /xxxxxx/yyyyyyy/app/controllers/invoice/inventory/department/pharmacy_invoices_controller.rb to define it):
```

I did ssh and checked every file on server. Its the same as development, which is obvious. I can't figure out why its throwing such an error in production.

Comment: Can you provide your rails version, webserver version and config/application.rb?

Comment: On server: Rails 4.2.3, ruby 2.2.1p85, unicorn (4.9.0),
On local: Rails 4.2.5, ruby 2.2.1p85, WEBrick 1.3.1,

In application.rb file I've this `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'controllers', '{**/}')]`

Comment: Please let me know what you need to know from application.rb

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the rails docs, specifically in [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#nesting-and-qualified-constants) and [Nesting](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#nesting).

This is because defining nesting can be done in 2 ways and are very different in terms of how its seen by rails. You can check this by using `Module.nesting`:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    Module.nesting
  end
end
=> [Foo::Bar, Foo]

class Foo::Bar
  Module.nesting
end
=> [Foo::Bar]
```

If you want to know more I recommend this really good blog post by Simon Coffey: [Rails Autoloading Hell](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/)